# What is meant by outstanding IO request in a host controller (e.g. HBA/RAID card)

Tags: storage, sata, hba, raid-controller

In context of a host controller (HBA/RAID card) which sends IO traffic to SAS/SATA drives which are part of logical volume - so in such setup, generally I hear a term "Outstanding commands". I did got somewhat understanding that these are number of IO requests which a controller can accept even if it already has some pending IOs which are not completed yet. So two questions here,

1) What would be a more complete (or more comprehensive) definition for `outstanding` IO commands ?

2) What is generic behavior of host controller when more IO commands arrives which is larger than its `queue depth` for holding outstanding commands ?

3) How `non NCQ` commands handled in such design ? Is it possible that in case of SATA drives where we have `NCQ` concept, a `non NCQ` command can starve for arbitrary amount of time ?

Answer (score 0):

I/O request packets used for communications between the device drivers and the operating system. It allows a particular process to get unblocked and for entirely executed